# How to send an Image from JavaScript to another HTML-Page?

Tags: javascript, html

I have to upload an image from my desk and send it to another html page to make a canvas puzzle.
This function display the image in the first page
JS:

```
function ParseFile(file) {
    // display an image
    if (file.type.indexOf("image") == 0) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            Output(
                "<p><strong>" + file.name + ":</strong><br />" +
                '<img src="' + e.target.result + '" /></p>'
            );

        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
```

and I have to send somehow to the other html page which usual receive an image like this: 
html:

```
<script>
var _img;
function init(){
        _img = new Image();
        _img.addEventListener('load',onImage,false);        
        _img.src = "img.jpg";
        audio.play();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have a Server?

Comment: No, i don't have a server

Comment: Well then you can't.

Comment: I didn't know that...